# Redux Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

The code is:

**Test component**:

```
import {add} from './../actions/';

class Test extends Component{

    _add = (){
       this.props.add(1);
    }

    render(){
        <button onClick={this._add}>add</button>  
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = ()=>({
    haha:'haha'
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    {add}
)(Test)
```

**Actions**:

```
export const add = value => (dispatch) =>{
    dispatch({
        type:'ADD',
        value:value
    })
}
```

I click add button there has this error!

What's the issue?

I looked createStore.js and `console.log(action)`. It shows a function.

But Redux's example is not a function. My code is almost the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) as a middleware, it will process dispatched function actions....

Another one is [redux-promise](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-promise) which will do somethink like the thunk ... but with promises

**UPDATE:**

This is a model to handle async

```
export const add = value => (dispatch) => {
   ... do something async
}
```

LIke this:

```
export const add = value => (dispatch) => {
   http.get('/path')
       .then(json => 
           dispatch({type: 'RESULT', payload: json}));
}
```

You action does not have async calls so it could be written like this:

```
export const add = value => ({
    type:'ADD',
    value:value
})
```

Comment: I did not use both `redux-thunk` and `redux-promise`.

Comment: And that's why redux is complaining.. to use async actions ... you need redx-thunk middleware

Comment: But I don't know where I have run async actions? I don't use **setTimeout** and there is no AJAX request

Comment: You don't... but the way you write the action... is used to solve async process...look my update

Comment: Is the reason closure? I notice it is a closure. Returns an anonymous function

Comment: I don't think it is because of a closure... I think it is because dispatch receives a function as a parameter... Then it passes to thunk middleware to handle it...

Answer (score 2):

You are simply missing the arrows `=>` in your arrow function:

```
export const add = value => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
        type:'ADD',
        value:value
    })
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't copy directly, I had made a mistake. Actually, the code is **=>**

Comment: You are still missing an arrow. And for this to work you need redux-thunk middleware.

Comment: Thanks ~ Let me try

Answer (score 0):

You should write your action creator like this:

```
export const add = value =>
  ({
    type: 'ADD',
    value: value
  });
```

The way you connect your action creator to your component (passing it with the shortcut notation `{ add }` as a second parameter to `connect`) allows you to omit the `dispatch` since `connect` will automatically wrap your action creator into a `dispatch` call when called this way.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't copy directly, I had made a mistake. Actually, the code is **=>**